# The meaning of Kernel density estimation

Tags: python, density-function, kernel-smoothing

So I'm attempting to design a graph which shows the density of points in 2D space (i.e. a contour plot) with some meaningful values attached to the contours/levels.

I've used two methods to try to understand KDE output.

[Seaborn's kdeplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) uses [statsmodels KDE PDF](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate.html) to get a 2d array of the probability density function.

[Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html) does the same thing (presumably) but outputs the log density. I'm assuming here that the log density refers to the log of the above PDF.

So I believe that if I integrate, over all space, the density (taking exponential of log density) of a KDE built from a sample of points, I get **1**.

[image: Log Density plot]

However, when plotted, this doesn't really help with the meaning. What is happening at, say, the middle contour level? My current understanding is that $\rm{exp}(-1.92) = 0.15$ and that number is the probability density of that level. Integrating that over the area of the level, $\approx 0.15 \times \pi 0.25^2 = 0.03$ gives me a 3% chance of point being located there.

It has been a while since I've looked into these things so a little explanation would be appreciated.

In the end, all I'm looking for is a meaningful way of displaying density on a 2D plot. I've seen plots displaying contours labelled as normalised density (with 25%, 50%, 75%... contours working out from the middle). This is the sort of thing I'm aiming for but not sure as to the meaning of it

code to reproduce above plot:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity

np.random.seed(1000)
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
data = np.vstack((x, y)).T

kde = KernelDensity().fit(data)

r = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(r, r)

plot_data = np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel())).T

log_dens = kde.score_samples(plot_data)

plt.contourf(X, Y, log_dens.reshape(X.shape), cmap='Purples')
plt.colorbar()
plt.plot(x, y, 'b.')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Normalized densities are essentially likelihood ratios, not true probability densities. They will no longer integrate to 1. Also, plotting the density values at 25%,50%,75% of the normalized max are not percentiles. To make this interpretable, you need to de-normalize and plot the level sets corresponding to some set of percentiles.

Note that the KDE using Gaussian densities will likely not be Gaussian.

Comment: Ok, so if the normalized densities from the kde are likelihood ratios how do I de-normalize them let alone get the percentiles?

Comment: @Lucidnonsense Not sure how to do it in python, but mathematically, you can divide the normalized density by its integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$  or you can find the point where the normalized density is 1, then determine its distance from each sample point and re-calculate the true density value at the that point. Then, you multiply all points by the true density of this point.

Comment: Typically KDE is done so that it gives you a true density out, ie integral 1. The two packages mentioned do this, so you don't have to worry about any normalization.

Comment: @Lucidnonsense I am not familiar with these packages, so if, as Dougal said, the densities are already properly normalized to integrate to 1, then you can find the level sets that integrate to the 25, 50, and 75th percentiles, for example.

Comment: @Dougal I looked for talk about normalization in the docs but I didn't find it. Can you point it out to me? Thanks

Also, I have no idea about how to start finding the percentile levels... (still looking)

Comment: @Lucidnonsense It doesn't say anything, because honestly it would be very strange to *not* give out normalized densities for KDE.

Comment: @Lucidnonsense Dougal is correct that it would be odd for it to give unnormalized densities, but, for example, R's "density" does not integrate to 1.

Comment: OK, am I being stupid?: I've just summed the densities `np.exp(plot_data)` and got an answer far greater than 1.
And anyway, I have a way to score samples i.e. `kde.score_samples`, but no way to solve for percentiles

Comment: Ah so surely I need a cumulative density to be able to display percentile contours or some way to integrate?

Comment: @Lucidnonsense yes, you'll need some way to integrate the KDE to get percentile contours.